# run a msql query after a specific amount of time without user interaction?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I will take the timestamp enter by a user as $tmp1
and server timestamp as $tmp2
I want to run a mysql query when $tmp1-$tmp2==0
I can do this by user interaction whith server
 and check it every time any user login, whether   $tmp1-$tmp2==0
but this will require redundant if statement every time .
can it be done using corn jobs or trigger I haven't used them before please help

Comment: This is easy to do however I would like to know why you want to do this? Most likely you are looking for the wrong answer to your concern.

Comment: "but this will require redundant if statement every time": huh? If its needed, its not redundant.

Comment: store time in db, use cronjob

Comment: there is a portion on a database where user can edit information only till a particular date/time(i.e dynamic) after that cannot, I want to make changes to accessibility after that specific time ends

Comment: And if you do the expiration when the user logs in, you know the expiration worked.  If you rely on a cronjob that breaks or doesn't run, then you don't know.

Comment: will trigger help in this case? else my question is redundant

Comment: So put that timeout field in the users record and each time a page loads or ajax script runs check that time when you check that they are actually logged in. Minimal if any overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there are 100 users interacting with another 100 user this came as 100*100 checking for the time every minute you should check up when user login or you can do is crate a event table and hit that event on a particular time

```
if event_time< now() and event_executed=0 then hit
```